# How do you use a JUNIT test to check if an entry has been added?

Tags: java, junit

I am creating Junit tests for my java program and its the first time using hashtables. I am very unsure on how to write a junit test to check if an entry has been added to the hashtable. Anyone got any ideas?

// This is the method which adds entries to the hashtable

```
public void add(String ph, Permit p) {
        PermitInfo.put(ph, p);
    }
```

// This is the start of the junit test

```
Permit_list test_permit_list;

    public void testAddPermit(){


    }
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/

Comment: How do you check if an entry is there? 1) check the entry is not there 2) add the entry 3) check the entry is there.

Comment: @ShakeDatBinary It is not very useful only because you want someone to give you the entire answer without showing any effort.

Comment: @ShakeDatBinary I can't image what else you need us to say. We can't do the work for you even if we wanted to as you haven't given enough details.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
String permitKey = "x";
assertNull(map.get("key").getId());
map.add("key", new Permit(permitKey));
assertEquals(permitKey, map.get("key").getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `yourHashtable`, for example in a `@BeforeClass` annotated method.

```
@Test
public void testAddPermit() {
    //here element variable has to be initialized
    assertFalse(element + "is not in the hashtable.", 
    yourHashtable.contains(element));
    //here add the element to the hashtable
    assertTrue(element + "is in the hashtable.", 
    yourHashtable.contains(element));
}
```

Comment: `assertTrue(!contains)` feels somewhat perverse - how about `assertFalse(contains)`?

Comment: Thought about that (was my first thought), but changed my mind... But if you say it's perverse... ok. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a public get method, then:

```
Permit_list test_permit_list;

@Test
public void testAddPermit(){
    Permit p = new Permit();
    test_permit_list.add("test", p);
    assertEquals(p, test_permit_list.get("test");
}
```

Comment: Using underscores is not part of standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: But neither is it forbidden.  Underscores can be, and are, used in internal naming patterns to orchestrate a variety of behaviors, particularly with regard to unit test naming (where annotations have not been adopted).

Comment: @scottb whilst I agree that it isn't forbidden, I have never come across using underscores in Java unit tests. Care to provide some concrete examples to explain their use?